# Special Characters in Anonymous Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create an anonymous type with a special character in the name of a variable

For instance I have this:

```
new { status = "Active" }
```

I would like something like

```
new { status = "Active", $exists = true }
```

This eventually serializes to JSON, so I know I can use JObject or something like that, but it would be much easier as an anonymous type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to stick to the rules! Your code won't compile because you are writing this as an anonymous type in code (not as strings) so the keys have to be identifiers in the language.

The language has rules. An identifier has to start with a valid `identifier-start-character`, defined:

> A Unicode character of classes Lu, Ll, Lt, Lm, Lo, or Nl

As per this rule:

http://www.jaggersoft.com/csharp_grammar.html#identifier-start-character

Using this table, the third column tells us that '$' is in the 'Sc' class, so you can't use it.

http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/UnicodeData.txt

If I were you I'd do one of three things:

1. fix your API specification so it doesn't rely on keys that are not valid identifiers in the language you are using (painful)
2. write a simple translation layer that re-writes your JSON before it gets sent (messy)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.  I'm obviously aware of the limitations on the compiler, I was hoping there was a work around.  Since it's just JSON serialized later anyway, I'll just create the object as a JObject.

Comment: Good luck with what you're doing!

Comment: Haha I wonder what mystery point 3 was. I'll leave it there, to make the answer more enigmatic.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have a hard time with that. Special characters are just that - special. They have important meaning to the compiler, and it isn't going to be easy (if not impossible) to defeat that.

Additionally, if you do manage to create a variable named `$exists`, you're going to create some confusing code. The `$` symbol has meaning in C# and jQuery, so anyone who reads your code may wonder just what is going on.

It's probably more trouble than it's worth, in my opinion.

Comment: You are correct, however it is only for serialization to JSON.

Answer (score 0):

your $exists will not work because in the end it gets translated to a property with the same name by the compiler. And on property values this naming convention is not allowed!